# How to retrieve the values of multiple checkboxes from admin forms

Tags: php, magento

I have a form in a backend module making use of some dynamically created checkboxes, done thusly:

```
$allStores = Mage::app()->getStores();
foreach ($allStores as $stores) {
    $store = Mage::app()->getStore($stores);
    $values[] = array('value' => $store->getId(), 'label' => $store->getFrontendName());
}
$fieldset->addField('checkboxes', 'checkboxes', array(
    'label' => 'stuff',
    'name'  => 'boxes',
    'values'=> $values,
));
```

Now for this particular example I have two stores, with respective IDs 1 and 2. I would assume that this would return an array, or string value containing either 1, 2 or 1 and 2. If I select both boxes, it returns 2, if I select store ID 2, it returns 2, if I select store ID 1, it returns 1. If checkboxes are not what I'm wanting to use here, what do I need to use to obtain multiple values from one field? I assume that this should be capable of it, or it had might as well be radio buttons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your html source

This is probably yours:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="boxes" value="1">1<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="boxes" value="2">2
```

This is what it should be:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="boxes[]" value="1">1<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="boxes[]" value="2">2
```

I don't know magento but a shot in the dark, I believe you might need to change your code to:

```
$fieldset->addField('checkboxes', 'checkboxes', array(
    'label' => 'stuff',
    'name'  => 'boxes[]',
    'values'=> $values,
));
```

Answer (score 4):

the following line needs to be changed:

```
'name'  => 'boxes[]',
```